# Style mat-table using flex

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

I have a mat-table that I want to configure using flex to grow to use the entire browser available space and display a scrollbar if the number of records don't fit.

I manage to do it by wrapping the table inside a div and assigning a static height to this div, for example:

```
.example-container {
  height: 800px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

But when I try using flex the table just overloads the available height:

```
.example-container {
  flex: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Please take a look at the project I created in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t9inn9?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sticky-header-example.css)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to define some sort of height in your container for this to work. This would be 90% of the browser vertical height.

```
.example-container {
  height: 90vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

**Update**

Here is solution using flex

```
.example-container {
  flex-grow: 1; 
  flex-basis: 90vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Revised answer to include flex solution.

Comment: Thanks, that is very useful but if I add another component that takes let's say the 20% of the browser the table will override the available space. I need it to grow if needed to cover the available space. Is this even possible?

Comment: I think one of the challenges you are having is working with flex in stackblitz. I played around with this some more and there appears to be an expandable container that you have no control over.  in index.thml of your stackblitz project replace all code with 20 of these <p>text</p>  and you will see a scrollable container that you cannot control, as it is the iframe that is being used to embed the rendered view into the "simulated" browser. You will probably need to move this out of stackblitz so you have absolute control over the root container height and the children can inherit via flex.